# Instantiating one of a family of classes given an enum

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance, enumeration

I'm trying to do something in Objective-C for an iPhone app and there isn't a good solution that I know of.

I have an enum representing classes A, B, and C that inherit from X:

```
typedef enum ClassEnum {
    X,
    A,
    B,
    C
} ClassEnum;
```

When my app was smaller, I used this to identify different types of classes, when they would be used, what should be done, et cetera.  Now that it's growing, I'm running into some problems.

I have another class which is a container for groups of these classes.  What I would like to do is have a constructor like this:

```
-(id) initWithClassType:(ClassEnum)type {
    //create 10 instances of the given class and add them to an NSMutableArray
}
```

Is there a way of doing this without having a giant `switch` in there that calls the appropriate constructors based on `type`? I feel like that has to be the wrong way to do something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
Class class = nil;

switch(type) {
    case A:
        class = [A class];
        break;
    case B:
        class = [B class];
        break;
    case C:
        class = [C class];
        break;
    case X:
        class = [X class];
        break;
    default:
        class = [X class];
        break;
}
```

This was followed by a call to `[[class alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a string representing thename of the class you want to alloc/init, instead of an enum. Then you could use that string to get the class object you need, with the NSClassFromString function. Something like this:

```
-(id)initWithClassName:(NSString *)className{
    Class *class = NSClassFromString(className);
    MyMotherClass *object = [[class alloc]init];
    ...
}
```